# how to replace special character using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

Am having this "�" special character in my excel work book, i want to replace all with ".", when i place this � character  in the code , it turns to "?" after i run the macro it replaces everything to "."

```
Sub FindReplaceAll()

 Dim ws      As Worksheet
 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   ws.Cells.Replace What:="�", Replacement:=".", LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

       Next ws
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue.  That icon is representing any number of characters that cannot be displayed on your machine.

Comment: [Unicode Replacement Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block))

Comment: If you can, go back and find the reason that � got into your workbook. It represents data loss due to incorrect character encoding conversion.

Comment: Hi @tom blodget the reason is am converting PDF to excel during that time all the dot are changed to that character

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy this character in a cell, then have the ASCII number and replace the character by the ASCII num:

```
Dim num =123
Ex:
    Cells.Replace What:=Chr(Num), Replacement:=".", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```